# How to add data in firebase through postman for this code?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, postman

```
module.exports.createNewProject = async (req, res, next) =>
{
  try
  {
    const userId = req.params.id;

    let userSnap = await firestore.collection("VideoEditor").doc(userId).get();

    let snap = await firestore
      .collection("Tier")
      .doc(`Tier${ userSnap.data().tier }`)
      .get();

    const tierInfo = myTier.getInstance(snap.data()); // Singleton class object

    let projectRef = firestore
      .collection("VideoEditor")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("Projects");

    let projectData;

    let docRef = projectRef.doc();
    let projectId = docRef.id;

    projectData = {
      id: projectId,
      name: req.query.name,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate(),
    };

    await docRef.set(projectData);

    let stateRef = firestore
      .collection("VideoEditor")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("State");

    docRef = stateRef.doc();

    let stateData = {
      projectId: projectId,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate(),
      timeline: {},
    };

    await docRef.set(stateData);

    myTier.destoryInstance(); // destructor

    return res.status(200).send({
      message: "Project Opened !",
      data: projectData,
    });
  } catch (err)
  {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I tried various methods but I'm not able to add data in firebase.
What credential I should take to add data through postman?
When I normally add the data through postman it show the error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tier') postman

Comment: Still struggling Mohit? Happy to help if you still don't know how.

Comment: Thanks for asking but I solved it earlier but I forgot to close the question.